# How can i off or on other app notification from my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

- Is it possible to configure other app notification from my app in
  iOS?
- I want to Off or ON notification of other app from my app.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Simple answer "NO".

Comment: I want something that launcher app do.

Comment: If the app is one of yours, you can use a custom scheme URL and by inter-app communication you can do it. But something such as settings is not possible

Comment: @NikitaKhandelwal , I am searching for the same thing. please share your findings or the point you reach at.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  An app can't change any of the settings for a different app.

Comment: I want something that launcher app do.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't support you to access settings of other applications. So you can't change it.

Comment: I want something that launcher app do.

Comment: I want a trillion tax-free dollars.